# Which log mentions when and who shutdown the weblogic server?

Tags: logging, weblogic, shutdown

Currently, we got a issue that is weblogic server is shutdown suddenly, we want to confirm if this shutting down is triggerred by human or by any exception.

So...is there anyone can tell me where cann i find the log info about shutdown weblogic?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at the last few lines of your server log file when it shuts down, that should give you a clue on what or who caused the server to shutdown.
Let me give you some scenarios when wls could shutdown 
1) Shutdown triggered from admin server console.
2) Force shutdown by calling kill -9 or control+c
3) JVM crash

For 1 and 2 you will see messages in the log file saying this.
For 3 it may not always be obvious. If you see nothing in the log stating why the server went down, then it must be a jvm crash.

JVM crash can leave behind a minidump file depending on what JVM you are using.
You might see stackoverflow error.

Usually to fix a jvm crash, one should upgrade to the latest minor version of that JVM. If the problem persists raise a support ticket with the vendor.